# How to set a custom string in Preferences screen?

Tags: android, download, sharedpreferences, settings, preferences

In my preferences.xml I have this option:

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/pref_header_storage">

        <Preference
            android:key="downloadLocation"
            android:title="@string/pref_title_wsl"
            android:summary="@string/pref_summary_wsl"
            android:persistent="true" />

    </PreferenceCategory>
```

And I was wondering if is possible to add a custom text for that preference, so I can show the current value of that preference to users.

So at the end the preference could be like:

> Downloads Folder
>
> Select a folder to save your downloads.
>
> Current selected folder: XXXXXXX

I want to add the last line in that preference, but I don't know how to do it.

May someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want the text to be shown as summary or do you want them below the preferences?

Comment: @Renges below the preference. Not as summary.

Answer (score 0):

Put your Preferences in PreferenceFragment. and then load it on your Settings Acitivity using this

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new PreferencesFragment()).commit();
```

Your Fragment for preferences should extends PreferenceFragment

```
public class PreferencesFragment extends PreferenceFragment
```

This way, you can edit the xml of your Preference Activity and add the text below the container for your Preference Fragment.

Example Code for Settings Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <FrameLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".SettingActivity" tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:foreground="?android:windowContentOverlay">
    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_below_prefernces"
        android:layout_below="@+id/container"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">

    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I already have the code of the fragment, to show it, the code to change preferences values, everything working. I just want to add that text in the preference (just in that preference (there are others)), but I don't know how to.

Comment: I have added Layout Code for the Activity. Can you check if it's that what you want?

Comment: It adds the text below the fragment. I want it inside the preference content.

Comment: Thanks anyways for your time